# Gravar Dados AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, array, post

Preciso enviar dados via ajax para gravar, e uma das informações é um array, mas a array perde posiçoes quando recebo ele no PHP, não sei se existe um limite de tamanho para o objeto AJAX enviado, caso tenha preciso dividir o array em vários como faria varios envios de dados na mesma requisição ajax?

```
var dadosPost = {
          'qtdNotas' : notasSelecionadasArray.length,
          'transacao': $("#transacao").val(),
          'flag_tipo_romaneio' : transacaoSelect.flag_tipo_entrega,
          'motorista': $("#motorista").val(),
          'veiculo':   $("#veiculo").val(),
          'placa':  veiculoSelect.placa,
          'ajudante1': $("#ajudante1").val(),
          'ajudante2': $("#ajudante2").val(),
          'notas': notasSelecionadasArray
      };



     if(validateState){
         $.ajax({
             //url da pagina
             url: $("#baseURL").val()+'romaneio/criarRomaneio',
             //url: $("#baseURL").val()+'/views/romaneio/tes.php',
             //parametros a passar
             data: (dadosPost),
             //tipo: POST ou GET
             //dataType: 'JSON',
             type: 'POST',
             //cache
             cache: false,
             beforeSend: function(){
                 $('.loading').css({display:"block"});

             },
```

A variavel notas é um array com várias notas selecionadas, para evitar problemas estou enviando a quantidade de itens contidos no array no JS para comparar no PHP mas isso limita a aplicação, preciso enviar um número maior de notas selecionadas.

```
   PHP
    $notasSelecionadas = ($_POST['notas']);
    $qtdNotas = ($_POST['qtdNotas']);
    $transacao = $_POST['transacao'];
    $motorista = $_POST['motorista'];
    $veiculo = $_POST['veiculo'];
    $ajudante1 = $_POST['ajudante1'];
    $ajudante2 = $_POST['ajudante2'];
    $flagTipoRomaneio = $_POST['flag_tipo_romaneio'];


    if(count($notasSelecionadas) >= 1){

        if(count($notasSelecionadas) == $qtdNotas){

        $dets = array();

        foreach($notasSelecionadas as $n){

            $o_romaneioDet = new RomaneioDetModel();
             $o_romaneioDet->setNotaFiscal(DataFilter::numeric($n['no_docto']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setCodCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['cod_cliente']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setNomeCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['razao_cliente']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setEndCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['endereco']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setCidadeCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['cidade']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setBairroCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['bairro']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setFoneCliente(DataFilter::cleanString($n['fone']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setFaturamento($n['faturas']);
                $o_romaneioDet->setSerieNotaFiscal(DataFilter::cleanString($n['serie_nfe']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setModeloNf(DataFilter::cleanString($n['modelo_nf']));
                $o_romaneioDet->setDtEmissaoNf(DataFilter::cleanString($n['dt_emissao_nf']));

            array_push($dets, $o_romaneioDet);
```

Comment: tentou usar assim: `'notas' :  JSON.stringify(notasSelecionadasArray);`

Comment: Isso que você está enviando é objeto não é? array não é {} é [] dai se for acessar no php por objeto seria dadosPosts->qtdNotas exemplo...

Comment: Vou colocar como faco no PHP.

Comment: é verdade o que @AndersonHenrique disse, se já estiver convertido em array faz só chamar no php você usar `$notasArray = json_decode($_POST['notas']);`

Comment: Como você está enviando o notasSelecionadasArray?

Comment: Não tenho problemas em Receber os valores, estou recebendo, o problema é que se envio 100 notas selecionadas, no PHP não chega as 100, dependendo da quantidade de informação contida no array notas, o numero de posições enviada varia, por exemplo, se pego 100 notas com Endereço Preenchido ou seja muito texto, chega apenas 40 nota, se pego notas sem endereço com menos informação ai chega 60...

Comment: Isso ocorre porque o POST tem limite de tamanho, oque você poderia fazer é encodar em json e no php usar o decode o limite é de 16.777.215 caracteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe os dados via `data: JSON.stringify(dadosPost),` e no PHP capture os dados, assim:

```
$dadosPost = json_decode($_POST['dadosPost']);
if (isset($dadosPost)) {
    // gravar dados no banco
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma nao deu certo, Da internal error 500

Comment: Agora funcionou, depois de fazer json_decode para acessar os dados tenho que usar $n->no_docto, agora estou conseguindo enviar 687 notas antes somente 44 obrigado!